# Apache Camel REST request HTTP error 403 Spring Security

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, apache-camel, http-status-code-403

I am using camel. The route (module 1 - camel-http4 component) sends a http4 request to a REST endpoint (module 2 - Spring MVC).

Using postman i'm not able to call REST services with basic auth (HTTP error **403**). All the calls from camel route fail and get HTTP error **403** (with STS).

I tried many options to get it working. (The problem may be from Spring MVC configuration ==> Spring Security).

Please help resolve this issue with some working example and explain the cause.

Comment: Can you access the target service directly? If so, change the logging level of `org.apache.http.wire` to `DEBUG` and check the raw log produced in order to see where your Camel HTTP client is doing something different than your direct call (via curl, postman, ...). With the current information given we can just guess what might be the issue

Comment: @RomanVottner I just changed the log4j settings in order to have more information. I am taking a look at the logs. Thanks